# PHP while loop separate from every 2 rows into a div

Tags: php

I have a while loop from database, but i want to wrap every 2 rows into a div.

Currently i have this but is only wrapping first row.

```
<?php
$get = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM sabiaque ORDER by ordem");
$num = 0;

while ($f = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($num % 2) {
        echo '<div class="divisor-slide">';
    }
    echo' 
        <a href="'.$f['link'].'"><div class="item-a">   
            <div class="box1-item-a">
                <div class="i-wrap"><h1 class="i-white">'.utf8_decode($f['titulo']).'</h1><p>'.utf8_decode($f['subtitulo']).'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box1-item-b">
                <img src="../'.$f['ficheiro'].'" style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
            </div>
        </div></a>
    ';
    if($num % 2) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $num++;
}
?>
```

Comment: `if($num % 2)` might be the culprit, try `if($num % 2 === 0)`, reason being that modulus returns the remainder, php loosly evaluates that remainder to true (if it's non zero)

Comment: Another option is to create grouping of your array data using http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php which then you can create a per row outer loop and a per colum inner loop, so your last div can be closed properly when you've got a single last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often find I get into a muddle using these special `$num%2` whatsits *(I'll get all excited in being clever in using them, then forget later what they do when I revisit the code)*. Why not simplify it like this (although it uses a little more code):

```
$num = 1;
while ($f = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ( $num == 2 ) echo '<div class="divisor-slide">';
    // rest of code
    if ( $num == 2 ) echo '</div>';
    $num++; if ( $num == 3 ) $num = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it was the solution indeed, after a little thinking i figured out it was simpler then i tought, i could simply make a var with a set value of 1 then in the while loop make an if condition to check when the var was 1 to start the div and then after the content adding a var if the var is 2 then reset the counter to 1 again which is pretty much your solution

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
if($num%2) {
  echo '<div class="divisor-slide">';
 }
```

By this :

```
if( ($num % 2) == 0) {
  echo '<div class="divisor-slide">';
 }
```

And this :

```
if($num %2) {
  echo '</div>';
 }
```

To :

```
if( ($num % 2) == 0) {
  echo '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: Consider to replace `==` with `===`

Comment: It is still not working, it is wrapping every first row but the second row gets not inside the div

Comment: because your count start to 0 start your $num to 1

Comment: Yes i  tought the same after replying but already tried it still the same, what changed is that it wraps every second row and the other is not wrapped inside the div